# How show content from tinymce on page and save editor styles?

Tags: reactjs, sass, tinymce

I use **dangerously Html** on page, but **global styles** on app changing tinymce style formatting. How can I *save style from tinymce* for showing.?
using react, nextjs, scss

global scss file revrite editor style(delete li, a, change color, fonts).
Usualy, builder has special file(content.css) and we can connect and styles from this file will apply to content if it simple div.

Problem: global styles change already formatted content. I tried to use an iframe, but is there really no simpler solution to show the content without changing its appearance?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways:
create own style file and describe all in it and connect for editor
add content in iframe